# c# rounding for xx.5

Tags: c#, rounding

Is it a good idea to write an extension method  for my application , and specify precision or is there any other **good idea** or other way to achieve **expected** results?

Due to the behavior of Convert.ToInt32 to truncate , I am doing something like **below** to achieve expected results

> **Note:** Application requirement is to have percentages as **Integer** and not **decimals** eg 50.50 is 51 and not 50.5 ,  TotalScore is an aggregation of other decimals (scores) , for accurate of percentage I wanted any xx.5 to be rounded towards tens

```
    public decimal TotalScore { get; set; }

    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "currentScore")]
    public int? CurrentScore
    {
        get
        {
            if (TotalCount > 0)
            {
                //eg 0.8149863 * 100 = 81.50 ~ 82
                //Convert.ToInt32 use Math.Truncate , so better to round it first
                //default MidpointRounding.Toeven SO : 2.5 ~ 2 and 3.5 ~ 4
                return Convert.ToInt32((Math.Round(Math.Round(TotalScore * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) / TotalCount);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            //Due to the fact WCF will fail with ReadOnly properties.
        }
    }
```

example:

`'0.8149863 * 100 = 81.50 ~ 82'`
`'0.2021111 * 100 = 20.21 ~ 20'` 
`'0.5889681 * 100 = 58.89 ~ 59'`

> **Note:** The behavior for Math.Round is as expected when closer to '0' or '10' , but above double rounding is done specially for 'xx.5'(and works for other cases) **Convert.ToInt32** uses truncate and makes no expense in getting accurate results

I need above behavior quiet a lot , so decided to write an extension as **below** , so to call the extension when calculating percentages on decimal and expecting integer value in return

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="count"></param>
    /// <param name="decimals">Number of decimal places </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int ToIntPercentageWithPrecision(this decimal value , int count , int decimals )
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32((Math.Round(Math.Round(value * 100, decimals, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) / count);
    }
```

However above solution is not readable and looks confusing . Need a clean and readable solution with accuracy.

Comment: Why are you rounding twice?  Why not just round to 0 decimals once?

Comment: Also, which part is not readable and/or confusing?  Would it be better to split your inline expressions into separate lines to explain the steps?

Comment: @DStanley Thanks for your reply , rounding twice is a bit ugly . if i use round to 0 decimals then 0.8149863 * 100 = 81 , but i expect 82

Comment: Break it over a few rows to make it more readable. Add comments as to why you are rounding twice etc and name the extension accordingly and it will look much better...

Comment: @AmitPore Why, 81.49863 is closer to 81 than 82.

Comment: return (int)(value + 0.5m) is easier on the eyes perhaps.  Expecting 82 out of 0.8149863 is calling the glass more than half full.  Add whatever you consider half-full.

Comment: @HansPassant Apparently 0.495m.

Comment: If 0.8149863 is closer to 82 than 81 in this use case, then what is 0.8133333 or 0.8122222 - where do you draw the line? How far do you extend this rollup logic down the decimal places...?

Comment: I suspect he's going to be tweaking that number for a while :)

Comment: Guys, he just needs a Math.Ceiling :)

Comment: @GeorgeLica Nope, if you round 81.111 to two place you get 81.11 and then round to 0 places gives you 81.  Ceiling gives you 82.

Comment: @juharr I updated my answer, now if you call ToIntegerPercentage(); for 81.111 it will give you 82 :)

Comment: @GeorgeLica But my point is that based on the OP's current code it shouldn't round it to 82 it should round it to 81.  What you've done it to round up for anything with a decimal value of 0.005 or more.

Comment: Dont understand why it has been downvoted ? , @GeorgeLica 81.111 should be rouded to 81.11 and end result to 81 and 82.

Comment: @AmitPore I don't think you should have gotten down voted, but you still haven't clearly explained why you need the rounding to work the way you are doing it.

Comment: @juharr thanks , I should update the question. TotalScore is an aggregation of other decimals (scores) , for accurate of percentage I wanted any xx.5 to be rounded towards tens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bascially you are rounding up for anything with a decimal value of 0.495 or higher.  So you could simplify the rounding by adding 0.505 (1 - 0.495) to the value and then just cast to `int` (the equivalent of truncating or taking the floor of the value).

```
public int? CurrentScore
{
    get
    {
        if (TotalCount > 0)
        {
            return (int)((TotalScore * 100) + 0.505m);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        //Due to the fact WCF will fail with ReadOnly properties.
    }
}
```

Comment: its missing TotalCount , hope (int) wont truncate. Will try it thanks

Comment: @AmitPore `(int)` will truncate, but by adding 0.505 it should increase it to the value you want to truncate it to.  So for 0.81498 it multiples to 81.498, then adds it to 82.003 and then truncates to 82.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an extention method like this:

```
public static class RoundingExtentionMethod
{
    public static int ToIntegerPercentage(this decimal d)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Round (d * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)));
    }
}
```

Then you could call

```
var result = (0.8149863M * 100).ToIntegerPercentage ();
```

Comment: put the *100 in the extension method (have it extend double instead of int)

Comment: @AgapwIesu Okay :)

Comment: @AgapwIesu Why?  The OP is working with `decimal` not `double`.

Comment: Then extend decimal.  Because if you are going to multiply times 100 every time you use the extension method then maybe that belongs in the method.  Or think of it this way - the extension method is to convert a fraction into a int percentage.  Why require the calling code to do the *100 before calling the method?  Of course this answer multiplies times a hundred in the calling code and then again in the method, so it does not seem right.

Comment: @GeorgeLica Not in your code, in AgapwIesu's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression in your extension method:

```
 return Convert.ToInt32((Math.Round(Math.Round(value * 100, decimals, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) / count);
```

Should give you the exact same things as just doing:

```
 return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(value * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / count);
```

I do not know why you even have the "decimals" parameter in that function as any decimals that the user puts in, get truncated by your outer rounding.  You really do not need an extension for this, just simply say

```
Math.Round(value * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

wherever you want to convert a fraction like .8149863 to 81%.  It is not technically correct to round .8149863 to 82%.  It is closer to 81%.  Your trick of doing the rounding twice does round it to 82, but that is not really the closer percentage.

Comment: It seems the requirement is to convert `.8149863` to `82%`, not `81%`.  Hence the slightly odd rounding.

Comment: @CharlesMager - yes, I was working on adding a note that rounding to 81 is not really correct rounding.

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough context to be able to just say 'your requirements are wrong'.

Comment: @CharlesMager - of course, you are right.  Which is why, from the start, I said "not **technically** correct".  He may not want to be technical about proper rounding.  In which case, he can ignore my answer.